# committing project to source control in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4

In Xcode 4, order to commit the entire project(all source files) to the source control repo, does one have to select all the files in the project navigator(Cmd-A) or is is it sufficient if I select just the Project file at the top and then File->SourceControl->Commit?

Comment: I most definitely wouldn't trust Xcode's source control though. Do you it manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you choose File > Source Control > Commit... (or press Command-Option-C), Xcode will list all changed files in the commit window.

If you right-click or control-click on a file and choose Source Control > Commit Selected Files..., Xcode will only list the files that were selected in the project navigator and have changes.

Comment: Updated answer:  choose Source Control> Commit.  That is, in the menubar.   It's no longer under File>     Restating: if you start the action from the menubar, it shows all changed files, if you start the action from a context menu in the Navigator, it shows only the change files beneath the file/directory where you clicked the right mouse button.