# Putting existing project under source control in Xcode 4.3.2

Tags: xcode, git, version-control, xcode4.3

I was looking for a way to put my existing project under source control, and I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618686/how-to-add-a-new-project-to-source-control-in-xcode-4?rq=1), but it looks like that solution only worked with Xcode 4.0 because I can't find a way to do what is advised. I also looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8349721/committing-project-to-source-control-in-xcode), but that solution doesn't work either because my project isn't currently under source control. How can I get my existing project under source control?

### Edit

I want it to be a git repository, not subversion.

Comment: Git; I'll specify that in the queston

Comment: Ah, I'm not to bad with svn, but awful with git =] Good luck

Answer (score 19, accepted):

you can do it in terminal using:

cd /to/app/folder

```
git init
git add .
git commit -am 'a descriptor of your first commit'
```

This should then be picked up in Xcode, you may need to close and re-open

Hope it helps

Comment: It be prudent to put the **UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate** file in `.gitignore` before doing the `git init` since it changes constantly but does not have anything to do with your code? This can be done by: `find . | grep UserInterface | sed 's:^./::' >>.gitignore` from within the app folder.

Comment: This is an old post, and I assume most of you already know how to do this, but I just wanted to point out that Apple now has a document that explains perfectly the process of creating a _git_ or _subversion_ repository for a project: [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_User_Guide/085-Save_and_Revert_Changes_to_Projects/manage_project_changes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010215-CH7-SW28). Hope this helps you.

Comment: You are right, @JoãoAbrantes, but I can't edit that link so I'll add a new one [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/xcode_guide-continuous_integration/PublishYourCodetoaSourceRepository/PublishYourCodetoaSourceRepository.html). Just scroll down to the bottom of that page, where it says "_Use Git to Manage an Unmanaged Workspace Directory on a Development Mac_".

Comment: Old post, but answer is still unique and relevant. Link has moved [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/xcode_guide-continuous_integration/PublishYourCodetoaSourceRepository.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get existing project by xcode (not command line), you can follow this:

1. Open "Welcome to XCode" window (below menu Window, or press Shift-Cmd-1)
2. Select "Connect to a repository"
3. Paste your git URL, and Next.

You can read more in http://www.mindthe.net/devices/2011/04/28/12-steps-to-using-github-with-xcode-4/

Answer (score 0):

Here're the steps that can achieve this, but requires cloning your existing project to a new one:

1, (Assume your project is not already under local source control) Create a new project under LOCAL source control (Please note that adding remote source control at this stage may not be successful)

2, Make this new project a clone of your old project - drag files, add frameworks, etc.

3, In menu "Source Control" ->  -> "Configure "
In the new window, click on "Remotes" -> "+" -> "Add Remote"

4, 
Name: anything (you can use "BitBucket")

Address: https://accountname@bitbucket.org/accountname/reponame.git

5, "Source Control" -> "Commit"

6, Select "push to remote" at the left bottom corner

7, Click "Commit"

8, Check on BitBucket website to see if it's actually pushed to it